# Finding xpath of element

Tags: html, xpath

In the following snippet

[image: HTML Snippet]

I want to get xpath of the element containing the text 'This is what I should get'. I use the xpath expression `html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/span`, but I am getting the element with text 'This is what I am getting'. Please help me to modify element locator to get desired text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a better XPath expression than that verbose one, but without more information I can only suggest based on the existing XPath. So, the desired text node can be identified either as text node that follows the previously selected `span` element :

```
..../table/tbody/tr[2]/td/span/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

or as direct child text node from the parent `td` element :

```
..../table/tbody/tr[2]/td/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: When I am using above xpath to automate some test scenario using Selenium and Java, I am getting exception org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException. The locator is: [object Text]. It should be an element @vxsx

Comment: @curious alright, there is no clean XPath solution in Selenium since it doesn't support returning other than element node. You'll need to return the `<td>` element, then do some string manipulation afterwards : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018524/selenium-get-a-text-node-using-xpath-and-use-it-as-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text node, the xpath would be:

```
html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/text()[2]
```

Although xPath expression should probably less verbose.