# In Selenium Webdriver, how can I get a text after an element?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I would like to get a text that exactly comes after a specific element. Please look at the sample code:

```
<div id="content-tab-submitter" class="">
    <h4>Sender</h4>
    <p>
        <span class="screenHidden">Name: </span>
        submitter
        <br>

        <span class="screenHidden">E-mail address:</span>
        submitter@asd.com
        <br>

        <span class="screenHidden">Account: </span>
        asdas
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

I would like to get the text that comes exactly after `<span>` which contains "Account".
By using this XPath expression:

```
//*[@id='content-tab-submitter']/p/span[contains(text(),'Account')]/following::text()
```

Java gives me an error, since the output is not a web element and it is a text. So, it is not possible to use findElement.

How can I get this text in a clean way? I mean I do not want to get all texts (in this case): submitter\nsubmitter@asd.com\nasdas and then extract the desired text.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that using just `findElement()`. Related question : [Getting text from a node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505375/getting-text-from-a-node/)

Comment: @har07 Thank you very much. Unfortunately, there is no other way!

Comment: yes there is a way plz check my answer below

Answer (score 3):

I think there isn't any straight possible way to extract text just after Account: i.e., an XPath expression which refers to text = 'asdas' directly.

So instead of trying to read exactly text = 'asdas' directly, try to read every text in the *p* tag and perform an operation like below to extract the tag.

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/rajnish/Desktop/myText.html");

// XPath expression for talking complete text i.e all text inside every span tag that comes under p tag
String MyCompleteText  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content-tab-submitter']/p")).getText();

System.out.println("My Complete Text is: " + MyCompleteText);

// MyCompleteText outputs in console:
// My Complete Text is: Name: submitter
// E-mail address: submitter@asd.com
// Account: asdas

// Now we have to split our MyCompleteText on the basis of Account:
// as we want text after Account: so do it like below

String[] mytext = MyCompleteText.split("Account:");
System.out.println("I am text after  Account: "+ mytext[1]);
```

And the output will be like this:

```
My Complete Text is: Name: submitter
E-mail address: submitter@asd.com
Account: asdas
I am text after  Account:  asdas
```

Comment: MyCompleteText gives:
submitter
submitter@asd.com
asdas

and does not give inner text insides span nodes!

Comment: sorry i am not able to get you are saying your are not getting any Name: E-mail address: Account : if yes then plz look i have also posted output and clearly shows all stuffs (inner text insides span ) indside the span nodes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a piece of JavaScript code to get the following text node:

```
// Get the targeted element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("id('content-tab-submitter')/p/span[contains(.,'Account')]"));

// Get the following text
String text = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent.trim()", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text, e.g., **asdas**, that comes exactly after `<span>` with innerText as **Account**, you can use the following lines of code:

```
// Identify the parent node
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content-tab-submitter']//p"));

String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[8].textContent;', myElement).strip()
// or
String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[10].textContent;', myElement).strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this works perfectly fine. If not, then please add a *div* class in front of the *span* class.

```
//span[@class='screenHidden'][contains(., 'submitter')][contains(., 'submitter@asd.com')][contains(., 'asdas')]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [getText()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()) method of Selenium, something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPath expression of the element")).getText();
```

Your XPath expression can be:

```
//span[contains(.,'Account')]/following::text()
```

Comment: Sorry but it is wrong, the text dose not belong to <span> element. I think I explained it clearly in the question and it is visible in the HTML sample. Please let me know if it is vague, then I will modify my questions. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I've modified my xpath