# In Selenium Webdriver, how to get an input element after a text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

In my case, there are some legacy web sites, in which not all the inputs have
id attribute properly set. Such as this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input id="unreasonablename" type="text" value=""></input>
</div>
```

But human testers can still test it by typing amount value in the input right behind "Amount". I'd like to make web driver do the same thing:

```
webDriver.inputAfter("Amount", 100); //I do not want to use "unreasonablename" to find the input.
```

But how can I find the input element after the text "Amount"? Thanks.

There is a relative question here: [In Selenium Webdriver, how to get a text after an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542323/in-selenium-webdriver-how-to-get-a-text-after-an-element). But I'm not familiar with xpath and do not know if my case can be solved in the same way.

Comment: Your Best bet would be using the xpath, if you dont have reliable id's.
Dont write it off because you dont know it.

Comment: `//div[label[text()="Amount"]]/input`

Comment: Thank you all guys and sorry for being late. I was just back from some other businesses. I works fine now with your help. Seems that you are all right :)

Comment: @DebanjanB Just done. Thanks for your tipping. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the `<input>` element just after the text **Amount** you can use the [**`findElement()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method along with the *Locator Strategy* as follows :

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Amount')]//following::input[1]"));
```

Comment: maybe following-sibling would be a better option

Answer (score 2):

you can try following_sibling as

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Amount']/following-sibling::Input"));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Amount']/following-sibling::input")).sendKeys("amount to be sent");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write some generic method like below. It can be used for all the required fileds by passing the label name and input value as argument

```
void enterInputAfterLabel(String labelname,String value){
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='"+labelname+"']]/input")).sendKeys(value);
}
```