# Selenium with Python: how to pull the data without id and class?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using python with selenium to pull data from the website below:
http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/klinik-fur-anaesthesiologie-und-intensivmedizin/info/4181

[Screenshot of Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TFlO.png)
As you can see from this picture. I want to get Hospital Name, Category, Address, Country, Phone, Website, and email.

But when I inspect elements, I found that there are no id, or class name to do.

**Category:**
General Hospitals

**Address:**
.....

I really have no idea how to pull them from this website.
Please help me or give me some advices.

Comment: Try using Xpath

Comment: You could just pull the `outerHTML` and parse it like a string.

Comment: If the language does not change then you can use some xpaths based on text or if the structure is the same, each time the same then you can try based on position.

Comment: do you know how to get them based on position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to find html tag  which contains 'Category' text (below c# code):

```
var category = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//b[contains(., 'Category')]"));
```

[edit]

to get text of that element:

```
var textOfCategoryField = category.Text;
```

and to grab values from other fields just replace string 'Category' for each element:

```
var textOfAddressField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//b[contains(., 'Address')]")).Text;
var textOfCountryField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//b[contains(., 'Country')]")).Text;
```

etc..

Comment: Thanks. I tried. It worked to pull 'Catergory:' from web page. But I want to get the text after this Catergory:. What should I do? Can i use Xpath to locate them?

Comment: use Text property on element

Comment: Thanks Jakub, now I can get the text "Category:" only. The original web source is like that <b>Category:</b>General Hospitals<br>, I cannot get the  text "general hosiptals".

Comment: ah sorry now I see that 'General Hospitals' is text node, try the solution described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505375/getting-text-from-a-node/