# How do I get the text from the li tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do I get the text from the li tag? I want to find the text "Password is required." only, not the text inside strong tag.

```
<li><strong>Error:</strong> Password is required.</li>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the html and your code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting text from a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505375/getting-text-from-a-node)

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your code for somebody to give a complete answer. I guess that you already know how to do something like the following

```
WebElement something = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(?))
string s = something.Text;
```

The next bit seems to be where you are stuck. There you need to parse the string s. That is nothing to do with Selenium-Webdriver. You could do something like

```
string[] s2 = s.split(new string[] {">","<"});
```

were the last element in s2 would be your answer here. This would be totally non generic though. Is this a situation in which you always want to purge html?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method developed in python.

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                textValue += child.textContent;
                child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

How to use in this:

```
liElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li")
liOnlyText = get_text_exclude_children(liElement)
print(liOnlyText)
```

Please use your possible strategy to get the element, this method need an element from which you need the text (without children text).