# Selenium: Only get direct text of element

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a html structure like this:

```
<div>
  My text
  <span class="c">Some other text I dont want</span>
</div>
```

In selenium how do I only get the direct child text of the div, in this case `My text`.

If I use `element.getAttribute("innerText")` I get this:

```
My textSome other text I dont want
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505375/getting-text-from-a-node

Comment: Yea that should work. Thanks