# Getting text() element in <p> with VBA/Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

Using Excel 2019 VBA, I am trying to get data from a paragraph on a web page with this structure.

```
<p>
    <strong>Release Date:</strong>
    " May 30th 2022"
    <br>

    <strong>From:</strong>
    <a href=URL>Title</a>
    <br>

    <strong>Performers:</strong>
    <a href=URL1>Name1</a>, 
    <a href=URL2>Name2</a>, 
    <a href=URL3>Name3</a>
</p>
```

This is the xpath for the paragraph.

```
/html/body/div[11]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]
```

To get the individual elements ("Release Date", "From" and "Performers"), I am having to parse the entire paragraph with "Instr"s or regular expressions.

***Is there a way to directly reference these elements with XPath?***

For example, the "Release Date" Xpath is:

```
/html/body/div[11]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]/text()[1]
```

I have tried to get this directly with the following but none of them work.

```
webdriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[11]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]/text()")(1) - Invalid Selector

webdriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[11]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]").Attribute("text")(1) - returns nothing

webdriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[11]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]")(1).Attribute("text") - returns nothing

webdriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[11]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]").text(1) - invalid procedure call

webdriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[11]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p[1]")(1).text - returns entire paragraph
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there an actual url?

Comment: Based on this, it seems that I can't get the date with XPath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506502/11792868.

Comment: You have the ability to execute JS so you can certainly get this. You can also easily transfer rendered content to MSHTML.HTMLDocument and do it using that DOM parser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the HTML doc. I'll give that a try.