# Xpath select text without tagname, attribute

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, text, attributes, tagname

i have a weired problem and hope u can help me. Is there a good way to read the marked numbers (123456789)?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="width: 98%;" class="TestClass">
            <span class="highlight-label">Person: </span>
            "123456789, "
            <span class="word-break">Lastname, 
            Firstname</span>
            ", geb. 01.01.1999"
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This xpath:

```
//div[@class='TestClass'][contains(.,'123456789')]
```

But its not reading just the Number, its reading like everything inside the Node.

Comment: You need to indicate what's known about the XML and what is unknown. Clearly some parts must vary otherwise you wouldn't need to look in the XML. Is the actual numeric value the only thing that can vary?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the solution in Python, check the below code with explanation:

```
# Store the element first
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='TestClass']")

# Below line will split the text by double-quote(") and then by comma(,) and store it into an array
split_text = element.text.split("\"")[1].split(",")

# print the first index of array
print(split_text[0])
```

**Console result:**

```
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
//div[@class='TestClass'][contains(.,'123456789')]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: Is there a way to just read the row with Numbers?

Comment: This XPath gives you the actual text you need....but I believe that with selenium you  have to find elements not text-nodes().
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506502/3710053

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed adding to your idea, this would return just the numbers with `lxml.html` `tree.xpath("translate(normalize-space(//span[@class='highlight-label']/following-sibling::text()[1]), '\", ', '')")`. Good to learn this `following-sibling::text()` ;-)

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Thats awesome, good to learn this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
//div/text()
```

This will return all text within that div

```
Text='
            '
Text='
            "123456789, "
            '
Text='
            ", geb. 01.01.1999"
        '
```

Then we need the 2nd value, so we reference the second found entry like this:

```
//div/text()[2]
```

In your case:

```
//div[@class='TestClass']/text()[2]
```

You might need to further adjust the retrieved value. But that should do the trick.

Source:
https://devhints.io/xpath